# OpenCV4 error: ‘CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: opencv, highgui

I recently migrated from OpenCV3.3 to the latest version OpenCV4 on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have some persistent issues with the installation. My installation did not give any errors when I followed [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-ubuntu-18-04/) installation tutorial. But whenever I include the module `opencv2/highgui.hpp` in my project, I get problems like below. This seems to be an issue caused by highgui.hpp when I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738634/opencv-error-in-highgui-hpp) link.

```
/home/arun/Documents/AutonomousLaneDetection/app/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/arun/Documents/AutonomousLaneDetection/app/main.cpp:118:36: error: ‘CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH’ was not declared in this scope
 int videoWidth = videofile.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/arun/Documents/AutonomousLaneDetection/app/main.cpp:119:37: error: ‘CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT’ was not declared in this scope
 int videoHeight = videofile.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/arun/Documents/AutonomousLaneDetection/app/main.cpp:123:27: error: ‘CV_FOURCC’ was not declared in this scope
                       CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10,
                       ^~~~~~~~~
/home/arun/Documents/AutonomousLaneDetection/app/main.cpp:123:27: note: suggested alternative: ‘CV_BLUR’
                       CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10,
                       ^~~~~~~~~
                       CV_BLUR
```

Comment: OpenCV 3.4 is *not* OpenCV 4. There is no "AKA." OpenCV has both versions, and they are separate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Those constants have been changed in name and location in OpenCV for some time now.

For the capture properties, they no longer begin with `CV_`, so remove that prefix from all of them. You can find a list of all available capture properties [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d), note that they all simply start with `CAP_PROP_`.

The `FOURCC` code constructor is a method on the `VideoWriter` class now, so you should use `VideoWriter::fourcc(...)`. The docs can be found [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#afec93f94dc6c0b3e28f4dd153bc5a7f0).

Comment: In addition to that, namespace should be stated at start of the class(Ex: "using namespace cv;") or it should be put before the enum (Ex: cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT).